# Starting a docusign flow from the API

Tags: php, docusignapi

I try to start the flow of a template defined in Docusign via the API. According to the code, it should work though my e-mail thinks otherwise.

The template contains a pdf and e-mail address to which the document should be sent to for signing. In the code below I create a new envelope based on template ID and would expect the email flow to start. I'm sure I'm missing something here.

```
$client = new DocuSign_Client($config);

$signatureService = new DocuSign_RequestSignatureService($client);
$result = $signatureService->signature->createEnvelopeFromTemplate('Subject','Blabla', '133455-157d-4795-929a-cc8d4a8b1a48');

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
class stdClass#12 (4) {
  public $envelopeId =>
  string(36) "d9267ac2-28e8-46d7-be74-133455"
  public $uri =>
  string(47) "/envelopes/d9267ac2-28e8-46d7-be74-133455"
  public $statusDateTime =>
  string(28) "2015-09-18T11:55:55.8230000Z"
  public $status =>
  string(7) "created"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, please provide links to the tools you are using such as the [DocuSign PHP Client](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client) - that will help people diagnose your questions faster.

The issue is that you are not setting the envelope's status to `sent`, which means it is simply being created and added to your draft folder in your DocuSign account (if you login to your developer account you should see the envelope in your draft folder).

Before you create the envelope you should do

```
$status = 'sent';
```

Then you'll need to include the status as the next parameter in the `createEnvelopeFromTemplate()` call:

```
$result = $signatureService->signature->createEnvelopeFromTemplate('Subject','Blabla', '133455-157d-4795-929a-cc8d4a8b1a48', $status);
```

Also, why are you using a template if you are not using any of your template roles on the template?  The templateRoles are another parameter on the `createEnvelopeFromTemplate()` that you are not setting currently.  This means once you get this working your recipient(s) will not have any tabs assigned to them.  Take a look at the tests folder in the GitHub repo for a full working example - [CreateEnvelopeFromTemplate](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client/blob/master/test/signature/examples/CreateEnvelopeFromTemplate.php)